# Storing XHR request into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

[image]I am having trouble storing the response of my XHR request.

Here is the javascript so far:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.open('get', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', true);
req.responseType = 'json';
req.send();
```

Over at chrome dev tools, i can see that response is the items i want so request should be fine. It is status of 200 and state 4.

The problem becomes when i try to write

```
var myJSON = req.response;
```

When i log this to console it responds with "null".
But if i reassign the value through dev tools, to exactly the same value, i get my JSON object.. Can someone please explain to me why and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with ready state

```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
    req.open('get', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', true);
    req.responseType = 'json';
    req.send();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          console.log(this.response);
var myJSON = this.response;
        }
      };
```

Comment: I added this code snippet: 
```
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200){
        var myJSON = req.response;
    }
}
```
Now its saying that myJSON is not defined o.O . Do u know what is wrong now?

Comment: I think u are trying to access myJSON outside the function

Comment: I added an image of the request if that helps you. I tried to see its content in dev tools to see if i can start working with it. I was trying to access it outside yes, i forgot the scope sorry for that. Is there a way i can have it outside to be able to work with it? 

Maybe declare it outside but assign value with the function?

Comment: It worked declaring the object, then assigning value the way u taught me, thanks alot again! And I appreciate the explanation! thanks one more time, was stuck at this for a while now :(